# Excel Counifs - adding simple criteria but not working

Tags: excel

I have simple countifs that counts open items between two dates and now I want to add another criteria and does not work. Both codes work as standalone codes but when combined give an error.

```
State   IssueDate   Due/Closed Date De      Date    Number  Number (A B C) only
Closed  12/12/2014  28/04/2015  DD      28/04/2015  1.00    
Closed  11/01/2019  04/03/2019  DD      04/03/2019  1.00    
Closed  05/01/2019  15/01/2019  DD      15/01/2019  2.00    
Closed  06/07/2016  28/10/2016  DD      28/10/2016  1.00    
Closed  20/10/2018  24/10/2018  DD      24/10/2018  1.00    
Closed  25/09/2016  27/09/2016  DD      27/09/2016  2.00    
Closed  24/07/2016  25/07/2016  DD      25/07/2016  3.00    
Closed  13/07/2018  22/07/2018  DD      22/07/2018  1.00    
Closed  05/07/2016  22/08/2016  A       22/08/2016  2.00    
Closed  02/04/2016  12/05/2016  B       12/05/2016  2.00    
Closed  14/07/2017  31/07/2017  C       31/07/2017  1.00    
Closed  03/05/2016  20/05/2016  DD      20/05/2016  1.00    
Closed  11/05/2017  18/05/2017  D       18/05/2017  1.00    
Open    09/06/2019  07/10/2019  XXX     07/10/2019  2.00
```

My formulas are to calculate Number of open `'=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$50000,"<="&F2,$C$2:$C$50000,">="&F2) + COUNTIFS(A:A, "Open",C:C, "<="&F2)'` and I have tried to add `COUNTIFS (F:F, ="A")`. I just can not combine it. If I know how to add A I will add B and C as well.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you adding the new condition in the same `COUNTIFS` function, or just adding it?

Comment: Try `=COUNTIFS (F:F, "A")`

Answer (score 0):

Put "A" in H1, then add the criteria to the original formula :

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$50000,"<="&F2,$C$2:$C$50000,">="&F2,F:F, "="&$H$1) + COUNTIFS(A:A, "Open",C:C, "<="&F2,F:F, "="&$H$1)
```